# Parsing the string in C#

Tags: c#

`"Vitrek.Inc,V63,0,FW2.06"` is the string i have and now I want to parse it to only get `"FW2.06"` in C# .Can anyone help?

```
string firmwareversion = buffer.Trim().Remove(0, 17);
```

tried this but get the whitespace infront of it

Comment: Try split around the commas.  The 3rd array results is the answer.

Comment: use google or do a search on this `C# stackoverflow string.Split`

Comment: how to spit around commas and get the third string

Answer (score 0):

this one should help

```
string temp = "Vitrek.Inc,V63,0,FW2.06";
string[] tempSplit = temp.Split(',');
string wordIwant = (tempSplit[tempSplit.Count()-1]).Trim();
```

it should solve your problem.
next time you need to be more specific.
for example:
"I need to get the last word when i split the string"

Comment: count() is missing a directive or an an assembly error

Answer (score -1):

```
string firmwareversion = buffer.Substring(buffer.LastIndexOf(',')+1).Trim();
```

`LastIndexOf` finds the *index* of the final comma in the `string`

Comment: but it comes out as " FW2.06" and i dont want the space behind FW